# Sharing variables between Python subprocesses

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, subprocess

I have a Python program named `read.py` which reads data from serial communication every second, and  another python program called `calculate.py` which has to take the real time values from `read.py`.

Using `subprocess.popen('read.py',shell=True)` I am able to run `read.py` from `calculate.py`

May I know how to read or use the value from `read.py` in `calculate.py`?
Since the value changes every second I am confused how to proceed like, saving value in registers or producer consumer type, etc.

for example : `from import datetime` 
when ever `strftime %s` is used, the second value is given 
how to use the same technique to use variable from another script?

Comment: Did you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157367/how-to-share-data-between-python-processes) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45066782/exchange-data-between-two-python-processes)?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest writing values to a .txt file for later reading